# How to UPGRADE from sylius-alpha to sylius-beta?

Tags: composer-php, symfony, sylius

i have a project that is almost done base on Sylius-alpha and now i want to migrate to Sylius-BETA , should i just run composer update or install sylius-beta and rework on sylius-beta again from the first ? what should i do plz ?

Answer (score 0):

I think alpha->beta has some BCs so you will need check everything you did, here upgrade from beta1 to beta2 https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/UPGRADE.md